# Hosting server IP address doesn't match A record but still resolves, website loads ok?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, a-record, resolve

Pretty confused by this, I have a website which is on a Fasthosts shared hosting package, the server IP is 213.171.xxx.x

However when you do a DNS lookup the A record is a completely different IP lets says 213.171.yyy.yyy

I have edited the files on the server and the website itself updates, so I am definitely looking at the correct files but I have no idea how it is resolving?

I might add that I have inherited this situation and I am stumped by it?

Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

213.171.yyy.yyy may be a [VIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_IP_address) used for load balancing or proxying.

In such a scenario, all trafic sent to the VIP, matching certain conditions (such as hostname: cosmicsafari.tld) will get redirected/forwarded to 213.171.xxx.x seemlessly

Comment: Was in contact with their Technical Team and this sounds exactly like their explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this is that the server has multiple IP addresses. You could check this with [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) e.g.

```
dig + short google.com
74.125.227.226
74.125.227.230
74.125.227.229
74.125.227.225
74.125.227.231
74.125.227.233
74.125.227.232
74.125.227.228
74.125.227.238
74.125.227.224
74.125.227.227
```